# Example of a pointer to class object in c++

Tags: c++

In the following code in main function, shape is declared as a pointer to class Shape object but the address of object of class Rectangle namely rec is saved in the following line.Can somebody please tell me where I am wrong in my understanding.

```
class Shape {
   protected:
      int width, height;
   public:
      Shape( int a=0, int b=0)
      {
         width = a;
         height = b;
      }
      int area()
      {
         cout << "Parent class area :" <<endl;
         return 0;
      }
};

class Rectangle: public Shape{
   public:
      Rectangle( int a=0, int b=0)
      {
        Shape(a, b); 
      }
      int area ()
      { 

         return (width * height); 
      }
 };
class Triangle: public Shape{
   public:
      Triangle( int a=0, int b=0)
      {
        Shape(a, b); 
      }
      int area ()
      { 

         return (width * height / 2); 
      }
};


int main( )
{
   Shape *shape;//pointer to Shape class
   Rectangle rec(10,7);
   Triangle  tri(10,5);


  shape = &rec;//address of Rectangle class object saved 
  shape->area();

  shape = &tri;
  shape->area();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you actually asking? Maybe you can clarify your question.

Comment: A Rectangle is a Shape. See "inheritance"

Comment: You need to go back and re-read the sections on object-oriented programming.

Comment: It appears you are doing a course or reading a book and you fell asleep/were on your cell during/skipped over the explanation of one of the core-fundamentals of C++. You should either tell your lecturer you totally missed the explanation of inheritance or you should re-read the chapter on it. This is not a language subtlety, or a bit of syntactic sugar, this is absolutely crucial to understanding C++. If you don't learn this, you won't be slightly handicapped as a C++ programmer, you won't be a C++ programmer at all.

Answer (score 3):

`Shape` needs to declare `area` as `virtual` to get polymorphic behaviour.

```
virtual int area()
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several errors and as the result the code has no a sense.

Consider for example constructor

```
  Triangle( int a=0, int b=0)
  {
    Shape(a, b); 
  }
```

Ar first the default constructor of Shape will be called because you did not specify a call of the Shape constructor in the ctor initialization list. So width and height will be set to zero by the default constructor.
Inside the body of constructor of Triangle you simply create a temporary object of type Shape that will be used never.

It could look the dollowing way

```
  Triangle( int a=0, int b=0) : Shape( a, b ) {}
```

or even as

```
  explicit Triangle( int a=0, int b=0) : Shape( a, b ) {}
```

if you know what explicit means.

Apart from this the class hierarchy shall be based on virtual functions that you could get the effect of the polimorphism. So class Shape should be defined the following way

```
class Shape {
   protected:
      int width, height;
   public:
      Shape( int a=0, int b=0) : width( a ), height( b ) {}

      virtual ~Shape() {}

      virtual int area() const = 0;
};

      int Shape::area() const
      {
         cout << "Parent class area :" <<endl;
         return 0;
      }
```

And uodate the derived classes according to these changes.

Answer (score 0):

`Rectangle` is derived from `Shape`, see the line

```
class Rectangle: public Shape
```

This is called inheritance or an "is-a" relation: a `Rectangle` is a `Shape`. Therefore, a `Shape*` can point to a rectangle. More info, can, for example, be found in [Base class pointer vs inherited class pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700786/base-class-pointer-vs-inherited-class-pointer) or most C++ tutorials covering inheritance.

As Roddy's answer notes, however, you should declare `area` in `Shape` as `virtual`, otherwise  calling `shape->area()` will always call `Shape`'s `area` method instead of the overridden method provided by `Rectangle`. Since `area` for `Shape` does not really make sense, you might even consider declaring it as *pure virtual*:

```
virtual int area() = 0;
```