# can we create object of class based on condition statement?

Tags: c++

I am creating a bank program where if acc_type is current then obj should be created of currentclass(derived from bank class) or else object should be created of savingclass(derived from bank class).can i use like this?i used it but it is showing error somelike 'obj' was not declared in the scope.[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN2Yk.png)

```
if(condition)
{
    derivedclass1 obj; //first object
}
else
{
    derivedclass2 obj; //second object
}
```

Comment: Please post error messages as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is:

```
baseclass *obj;
if(condition)
{
    obj = new derivedclass1; //first object
}
else
{
    obj = new derivedclass2; //second object
}
```

There's other ways of doing this (I'd personally use a [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)), but this is the easiest to understand.

Comment: will it not create an object of class bank?

Comment: No, the `new` statement explicitly creates the subclasses `currentclass` or `savingclass`. Here's [a more detailed look at pointers to base classes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2700786/1270789).